# How to call Django API with Javascript with Authenticated user in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

*I'm using Django for Backend, PostgresSQL as DB and HTML, CSS and Javascript as Frontend.* I am calling Django API via Javascript. Where user is adding a product to a cart, and I'm calling the cart with DRF to show all the data to the user. But problem is that, user can see all the data of other user. So, how can authenticated user can see his/her selected product on a cart.

**Here is a detailed code:**

**views.py**

**`adding product to cart`**

```
def addProduct(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product_cart = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user, product=product_cart).save()
    return render(request, 'cart/addtocart.html')
```

**Api View (views.py)**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def showproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = Cart.objects.all()
        serialize = productserializers(result, many = True)
        return Response(serialize.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class productserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**Javascript to call Django API**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/showproduct/',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
          var row = 
          $('<tr> .. ..........</tr>');
          $("#table").append(row);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

**NOW, How to show the specific user(authenticated user) there specific cart item.**

Comment: to get `Cart` data of particular user you have to pass `request.user` in your `result = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: Hello @AnkitTiwari, Can you please Display the detail code. It will be appreciated

Comment: did your user is authenticated when he add products to cart ?

Comment: Yes ,in 'DJANGO ADMINISTRATION' i can see cart having user, id and selected product.

Comment: no i mean when user add product to cart is he logged in or not

Comment: yes, he has to be logged in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233789/discussion-between-santosh-chauhan-and-ankit-tiwari).

Comment: Hello @santoshChauhan let me know if there is an error

Comment: Hello @AnkitTiwari it showing an error as `showproduct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`

Comment: you have to pass `id` inside `showproduct(request, id)` and i forgot to tell you because you din't provided your `urls.py`

Comment: you have add id in your `urls.py` also like this `showproduct/<id>/`

Comment: `path('addProduct/', views.addProduct, name ='addProduct'),
path("showdata/", views.showproduct, name='showdata'),`

Comment: change this `URL`  `path("showdata/", views.showproduct, name='showdata')` like this `path("showdata/<id>/", views.showproduct, name='showdata')`

Comment: Hello @ santoshChauhan did it worked?

Comment: Now, I'm implementing it, because the data which I present of javascript is not implemented yet. The JS is first implemented on first project. this is my second project. I will let you know sir

Comment: Hello @AnkitTiwari, what is mean by this: `url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/showproduct/'+your_user_id+'/',`. I cant understand your_user_id. Which user id sir, I'm totally feeling like noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass user id when you are calling ajax.
If you are using `GET`method than pass user id in `URL` and access it via argument in your view for eg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '{% url "showdata" %}',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
          var row = 
          $('<tr> .. ..........</tr>');
          $("#table").append(row);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

and in your `views.py`

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def showproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serialize = productserializers(result, many = True)
        return Response(serialize.data)
```

and add this in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("showdata/", views.showproduct, name='showdata')
]
```

**UPDATE**

there is no need to pass user id in ajax `URL` if user is authenticated than user will come in `request`
so please change you `views.py`, `urls.py` and `ajax URL`.